# Same FCM token receiving after installing new iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I integrated FCM notifications in my app. Whenever installed the app that time FCM token(ex: **'X'**) generated, then deleting the app and installed again I am getting the same FCM token **X**. After a close and open the app getting new token.Could you please help me to  resolve this issue.

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

  pod 'FSPagerView',            '0.8.2'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'CustomIOSAlertView',     '0.9.5'
  pod 'FreshchatSDK',           '2.9.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON',             '4.0.0'
  pod 'Charts',                 '3.2.2'
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/CoreOnly'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '6.5.0'
  pod 'GrowingTextView', '0.6.1'

end

target 'MYAPP' do
  all_pods
end
```

Comment: check whether your project contains two firebase intilization

Comment: No, it's not initializing multiple times.

Comment: check other dependencies whether those are using firebase or not

Comment: Other dependencies not using firebase

Comment: share your podfie

Comment: I added my podfile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227780/discussion-between-bathi-and-chowdhury-md-rajib-sarwar).

Answer (score 0):

every time you get FCM token from user and store it on server, check whether FCM token for that user is already present or not. If is present then replace it. If not add the new one.add this func to your app delegate!
so for this scenario put the code inside the regular didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate function, I can get the refresh token every time

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

    if let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid { // user is signed in

        Firestore.firestore().collection("userProfiles").document(userId).updateData(["fcmToken": fcmToken]) { (error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }

        }

    }

}
func application(_ application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
}
}
```

Comment: But in my case, I am receiving the last uninstalled build token.

Comment: I updated the code in order your problem. let me know what happend then:)

Comment: unable to use instance id, because i am getting compiler error

Comment: Please find my code here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7387

Answer (score -1):

I used the below code and it's working fine in debug not working in relese build.

```
Messaging.messaging().retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID: fcmSenderID) { [weak self] (token, error) in

            if let fToken = token {
                
                print("FCM: \(fToken)")
               
            }
        }
```